# body onload and jQuery ready order MS IE & Edge

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

When I have both events (ie body onload and jQuery ready) in one simple page (without images etc), body onload event fires before jQuery document ready in IE and MS Edge. Common order in other browsers is reverse. Why? How to achieve normal order?

Sample code:

```js
$(function() {
  console.log('ready - second in ie');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="console.log('body.onload - first in ie');">
</body>
```

Edit:

For this moment I've solved this by this way: instead of `<body onload="Foo();">`
I use:

```
  $(function(){ 
    window.setTimeout(function() { 
      Foo(); 
    }, 0); 
  });
```

Now `Foo()` fires later then other document.ready scripts, no matter when I register it.

(This is solution for old project, where is not possible to rewrite and test all onload events to document.ready events).

Comment: Use jQuery for load too: jQuery("body").on("load", function(){ console.log("...")});

Comment: This is not solution. Where I should register  jQuery("body").on("load", function(){ console.log("...")});? It's late to do it in $(function(){}), because onload fires before document.ready. And is not posible to do it earlier, because body doesn't exists yet.